# Apache mod rewrite url htaccess

Tags: apache, url, url-rewriting

I am a little bit confused and still learning on how to rewrite in Apache htaccess

How can I turn this:

http://www.mydomain.com/dir1/post.php?%20id=1

into this:

http://www.mydomain.com/category1/post/1

This is my reference, I'm not sure if I am doing it correctly

```
<a href='http://www.mydomain.com/dir1/post.php? id=$id'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple rewrite rule if you only need to rewrite a single URL.

```
RewriteRule ^dir1/post.php?%20id=1 category1/post/1 [L]
```

or you may need to replace the %20 with the whitespace character regex

```
RewriteRule ^dir1/post.php?[\s]id=1 category1/post/1 [L]
```

You will need to make sure mod_rewrite is on as well ('RewriteEngine On' in .htaccess).

Here is a good tut: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

Comment: thank you so much for the help sir ill try what you are suggesting to me... sorry for bad english... i appreciate your help.. godbless

Comment: hi there..amm its me again i wanna ask if the location of file .htaccess [in my case it is located at the /public_html] has something to do on its effect? what i did is this.. RewriteEngine on RewriteRule ^dir1/post.php?%20id=1 category1/post/1 [L] <-- and added this line above.. im having a little bit problem thinking i might placing the htaccess file incorrectly.. thank you sir

Comment: Try replacing %20 with [\s]. This is a regular expression for whitespace characters. If that doesn't work, try the suggestions [here](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-134799.html).